# is geforce GT 710 is suitable for blender and adobe systems learning?

Tags: adobe, blender, adobe-premiere

I need a help on a decision whether to buy GT-710 for more of Blender or Adobe work. 
Although it fits right in my budget, I can try new suggestions.
 Kindly do me a favor. 
I am tired of looking in the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say no. You would run fast into its limits and you would not be able to finish your models. I have a GTX 960 it is also old but it works fine with Blender to a certain point. I would suggest an older card but a little more powerful regarding VRAM. GTX 960 colst like 80 $ now used so I think it would be better.